# Is it possible to update only a selected linked object in PPT?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to build a macro which will update only the selected linked object within a PowerPoint, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

The first part below is what I've used to update all linked objects, but I am currently dealing with massive Excel files, and presentations with 200+ linked objects, so one-at-a-time updating is the only way to go unfortunately.

The second part is what I was hoping would work.

First part:

```
Dim sld As Slide
Dim sh As Shape

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each sh In sld.Shapes
        If sh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
            sh.LinkFormat.Update
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Second part:

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection
    .LinkFormat.Update
EndWith
```

I'm pretty inexperienced with PPT VBA, so please bear with me. Is it possible to build something like this? (It's going to be part of a more complicated macro, so it ultimately will be more convenient than just Right Click + Update Link)

Comment: For starters, you need to check the `.Type` of `Selection` - see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.selection).

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub UpdateOLELink()
  ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.LinkFormat.Update
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Correct me if I'm wrong, John, but doesn't that update all links in the PowerPoint? A specific way to update only one selected, linked object is what I'm looking to do.

Comment: The inclusion of the Selection object ensures that only the selected object is updated.